# queueing systems

Tags: linux, message-queue

I need to implement a new project, one which processes on three different servers will pull from.

Basically, one system will fill up a queue, then each individual system will pull from that queue (pop a job / message), and do it's business.  So essentially, in a standard FIFO, the processes on the child servers will do the popping.

Of all the queuing systems out there, what are some recommendations?  I looked into RabbitMQ but that's more of a "push", and like I said, I need a "pull"?  I really don't want to build one, just grab some thing that works.  OF course it has to be open source   :-)

Thanks

Comment: It seems like messaging is the hard part that you would want a library for. 'Push' / 'Pull' is up to your specific implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at beanstalkd (a python based queuing system). Its pretty simple, but extremely fast and bit flexible. I have used it on the EC2 cloud, queuing and servicing(deleting) about 500 jobs/min, where the queue was simultaneously accessed by 100 machines.